# How to make a list cyclically adjacent pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list (for example) $\{1,2,3,4\}$. I want a list $\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,1\}\}$ where only the elements that are "cyclically adjacent" in the input list are in the output list.

Comment: `Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]`

Comment: This uses the extra of arguments of `Partition` to (in order): make lists of length `2`, such that each list begins `1` after the start of the previous one, and such that the `{first, last}` elements of the result are the elements appearing at `{1,1}` of `list` (i.e. it both starts and ends with the first element of the list)

Comment: @thorimur   I really appreciate the explanation.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list={1,2,3,4};

Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways  to do this. Another is

```
lis = {1, 2, 3, 4}
MapThread[List, {RotateRight[lis], lis}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the order the same as you show, then do

```
 Sort[MapThread[List, {RotateRight[lis], lis}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Or first, change the list, then Partition.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} // Join[#, {First@#}] & // Partition[#, 2, 1] &
```

Comment: Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1, 1]

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};

Transpose[{#, RotateLeft @ #}] & @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}
> ```

Also

```
Partition[Riffle[#, RotateLeft @ #], 2] & @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[list /. {a_, b__} -> {a, b, a}, {_, _}, Overlaps->All]
```

{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Using `MovingMap`:

```
RotateLeft@MovingMap[# &, list, 1, 4]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}*)
```